# Three.js THREE.DoubleSide not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, internet-explorer-11

I've imported a collada (dae) model into my Three.js scene and that works perfectly.  I've created a MeshPhongMaterial and applied it to one particular object in the scene and on Chrome/FF it works as expected, but in IE11, setting THREE.DoubleSided causes the material to not be drawn.

I'm guessing there's an issue with the shader and IE11, but wondered if I might be missing something or is someone has a solution:

```
var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "meshes/demoRoom/textures/Tank_COLOR.png" );
var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( 
{ 
    map: map, 
    side: THREE.DoubleSide, 
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, 
    depthTest: true, 
    transparent: true, 
    opacity: 0.35,
    ambient: 0xffffff, 
    color: 0xFFFFFF, 
    specular: 0xcccccc, 
    shininess: 20, 
    emissive: 0xFFFFFF, 
    shading:THREE.SmoothShading 
} );
```

Comment: (1) Loading is asynchronous. Are you sure you are calling render() after the texture loads? (2) Is your background white? Set `emissive = 0x000000;`

Comment: Yes, rendering for sure, and I've both set emissive to white, removed it (default is black) etc.  I think it's the shader support in IE11 unfortunately.

Comment: I'm getting "WEBGL11095: INVALID_OPERATION: clearStencil: Method not currently supported" as well as "gl_FrontFacing" not being declared correctly

Comment: I've also written a multiloader that works with Threes loading manager and so, I'm not constructing the scene / assets until after all assets are preloaded.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn358557(v=vs.85).aspx

Stencil buffers are not supported.